# how to Pass only positive values from datagridview1 to datagridview2 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I had this problem on how to pass only the data which are positive  from a specific row in datagridview1 to datagridview2.

For example;

This is my data in datagridview1

```
 Code     ProductID    Description           Balance
 C1        0001        Office Furnitures     10,000.00
 C2        0002        Steel Cabinets        10,000.00
 C3        0003        Swivle Chair           3,500.00
 C4        0004        Monitor               -5,000.00
 C5        0005        Keyboard                -750.00
 C6        0006        Mouse                   -500.00
```

Pass only the data which has a positive values to Datagridview2

```
 Product Description         Balance
 Office Furnitures          10,000.00
 Steel Cabinets             10,000.00
 Swivle Chair                3,500.00
```

I already tried this code and it works fine but passes all the data from datagridview1 to datagridview to including the rows that has negative values:

```
 Dim n As Integer = 0
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvSTSub.Rows
        If dgvSTSub.Rows.Count <> n + 1 Then
            StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows.Add()
            StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value = r.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows(n).Cells(1).Value = r.Cells(0).Value
        End If
        n += 1
    Next
```

I do not know how to twist the code for me to get the result. any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own problem. This is the code if you are interested. ENJOY!

```
 Dim n As Integer = 0
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvSTSub.Rows
        If dgvSTSub.Rows.Count <> n + 1 Then
            StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows.Add()
            If r.Cells(0).Value > 0 Then
                StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value = r.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
                StudentTransaction.dgvReceipt.Rows(n).Cells(1).Value = r.Cells(0).Value
            End If
        End If
        n += 1
```